# Как правильно передвигать препятствия в ранере?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю ранер под мобилки, и исходя из того что я прочитал про разработку ранеров я понял что надо передвигать игровые объекты на встречу персонажу, а не персонажа двигать по игровому миру. Проблема такая, я не могу понять как делать это плавное передвижения препятствий в сторону персонажа и так чтобы это не вызывало подвисаний. Смотрел в сторону transfrom.Translate() но сомневаюсь в правильности этого решения т.к в один момент в видимой области может находится до 50 объектов (препятствия, монетки и т.д), поэтому не думаю что вызов этого метода для 50 объектов каждый каждый кадр это лучшее решение. Собственно как лучше сделать плавное передвижение объектов?

Comment: Для таких вещей используют `Waypoints`, либо более продуманный `NavMesh`, все остальное костыли и велосипеды.

Comment: Что и как двигать - не столь важно. Делайте как вам проще. Двигайте персонажа с камерой вперед, а весь мир назад на то же расстояние. Получится как вам надо.

Comment: @And это вообще из другой оперы

Comment: @kromster т.е одновременное передвижение 50 объектов по производительности на мобилках не сильно ударит и можно передвигать таким образом? Ну и двигать перса вперед а мир назад это избыточно, тоже самое что и двигать элементы в сторону персонажа))

Comment: @Kromster, вы уверены? Вы делали так? Что если будут препятствия для движения или лабиринт? Вы будете самостоятельно изобретать расчет физики движка и все траектории mesha? Когда уже в самом движке есть навмешы и вайпоинты.

Comment: @And почитал про то что вы написали, как я понял это про передвижение исходя из некоторых условностей (т.е стоит стена и надо её обходить), а мне не это надо мне надо просто двигать объекты  по одной оси и так чтобы при большом количесте этим элементов (50) не было просадок в производительности

Comment: @And Раннер это довольно специфический жанр. Почитайте про него

Comment: Тут зависит от того КАК вы двигаете. Если на всяких таймерах, то конечно будет жесть. Погуглите, как в Юнити правильно делать аркады

Comment: 50 трансформов за кадр - детские цифры, ничего подвисать не будет, как даже если в сотню таких объектов сдвинете. Никакие навмеши использовать не нужно. Если хотите написать более оптимальный код - не используйте для каждого объекта GameObject, что для новичков является довольно трудной задачей.

Comment: @And Я уверен, я так не делал и не собираюсь. Навмеши никак не связаны ни с данной задачей, ни с "расчетом физики движка", агенты оперируют сугубо исходя из навмеши, которая никакого отношения к физике не имеет в своей базовой реализации.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Спасибо за ответ . А можно поподробнее про то как это не использовать для каждого объекта gameObject?

Comment: Просчет коллизий у вас примитивный, так что свое простое решение можно написать, отрисовка объектов может производиться из отдельного кода, а не благодаря MeshRenderer'у. В целом этот вопрос достаточно общий и вот так просто на него в комментариях на него трудно ответить, не зная всех тонкостей конкретного проекта.